# How do I switch my weapon?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I have my starting weapon equipped, but I can't figure out how to use my bow now. If I press <kbd>f</kbd>, it says that I don't have a weapon to fire. I'm holding a bow and a quiver with arrows though. I assume that I need to equip it, but I can't figure out how. I also have a couple other weapons that I can use with <kbd>A</kbd> if they aren't in my backpack, but I'm not sure how to equip them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to <kbd>w</kbd>ear a quiver and <kbd>r</kbd>emove the bow from your backpack into an open hand. If you don't have an open hand, you need to <kbd>p</kbd>ut whatever you are holding into your backpack or <kbd>t</kbd>hrow/<kbd>d</kbd>rop it.

Comment: I think, but not completely sure, that not having an free hand next to the hand holding the bow, increases your reload time. Don't know if that is testable. But you should watch out, it is easy getting beaten to death while reloading.